# How to set a value of a variable in a "child" javascript file from the "parent"?

Tags: javascript

In my index.php I have a script which toggles a sidebar.

```
$(function() { 
            // Open the Sidebar
            $(".sidebar.right").trigger("sidebar:open");
            // Toggle the Sidebarbutton to close
            $(".open-close-button").toggleClass("open");

            count = "1";
        });
```

There is a "open/close" button which toggles the sidebar aswell. - Now, if i set the sidebar to "open" I need to tell the toggle-button to close, if someone clicks it - and I do that by setting "count" to "1".

"Count" is a "global-variable" - I think. I´m new to javascript, but it´s in no function. Look here, thats the "sidebar-toggle-script" sidebarhandlers.js:

```
    var count = "0";
    var open = "open";
    var close = "close";

$(".sidebaropenclose").on("click", function () {

    var $this = $(this);
    var side = $this.attr("data-side");

    if (count == "0") {

        $this = $(this);
        side = $this.attr("data-side");
        $(".sidebar." + side).trigger("sidebar:" + open);
        count++;
        return false;
    } 
    if (count == "1") {

        $this = $(this);
        side = $this.attr("data-side");
        $(".sidebar." + side).trigger("sidebar:" + close);
        count = 0;
        return false;
    }
```

In the "header" of my "index.php" I initialize the script with:

```
<script src="js/sidebarhandlers.js"></script>
```

The question is how i send the "count" from my "index.php" to "sidebarhandlers.js". - My version doesn´t work.

Comment: Problem solved! The variable was no global. The code works.

Comment: Don't put quotes around numbers. And you should use booleans for `true/false` states.